# Is there a way to determine the Hostname or IP of a computer given the AD user account logged in?

Tags: windows, networking, active-directory, powershell, users

If I know John Doe is logged into a workstation on my network, is there a way to determine what computer he is on using his account, in Powershell preferably.

Comment: You could do this by enabling Kerberos auditing on your Domain Controllers. Then just look for eventID 4769 containing the target username. This event will provide the IP of the computer being used. If NTLM authentication is being used, then look for eventID 4776. This will provide the hostname and not the IP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have a tool to do this, I'm guessing you don't have a super large inventory. One way you could do this is to inventory all the computers in AD (in this example, Windows 7 or Windows 10). Then check each of those computers for who is logged in.

```
$TheseComputers = (Get-ADComputer -Filter {OperatingSystem -Like "Windows 7*" -or OperatingSystem -Like "Windows 10*" } -Property *) 

foreach ($Computer in $TheseComputers) {
    Get-WmiObject –ComputerName $Computer.name –Class Win32_ComputerSystem | Select-Object UserName
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This works. In the future I'll try to create a custom attribute that the host-name or IP is written to when they login. And maybe a logoff script to clear it.